# How to force PHP to take the correct php.ini?

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, configuration-files, php-7, php-ini

I have two PHP versions on a Windows Server -- `v5` and `v7`. The problem is, that PHP 7 tries to use the `php.ini` of PHP 5:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.2 (cli) (built: Jan  6 2016 12:59:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         D:\path\to\php5\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

**How to set the correct `php.ini` for PHP 7?**

Comment: Does `echo %path%` show `D:\path\to\php5`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver It show both -- the path for PHP5 and the path for PHP7: `...D:\path\to\php7\ext\;D:\path\to\php5\ext\;D:\path\to\php7\;D:\path\to\php5\;D:\path\to\php5;...`.

Answer (score 1):

The following manual page discusses how PHP finds its configuration-file in Windows:

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

> SAPI module specific location (`PHPIniDir` directive in Apache 2, -c
>   command line option in CGI and CLI, `php_ini` parameter in NSAPI,
>   `PHP_INI_PATH` environment variable in THTTPD)
>
> The `PHPRC` environment
>   variable. Before PHP 5.2.0, this was checked after the registry key
>   mentioned below. As of PHP 5.2.0, the location of the php.ini file can
>   be set for different versions of PHP.
>
> The following registry keys are examined in order: 
>   `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y.z]`,
>   `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y]` and
>   `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x]`, where `x`, `y` and `z` mean the PHP
>   major, minor and release versions. If there is a value for `IniFilePath`
>   in any of these keys, the first one found will be used as the location
>   of the php.ini (Windows only).
>
> `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP]`,
>   value of `IniFilePath` (Windows only).
>
> Current working directory (except CLI).
>
> The web server's directory (for SAPI modules), or directory of
>   PHP (otherwise in Windows).
>
> Windows directory (`C:\windows` or `C:\winnt`)
>   (for Windows), or `--with-config-file-path` compile time option.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I checked my registry, but there are no entries for PHP there. (Only "PHP Manager", but it's something for IIS.)

Comment: I tried many things out yesterday to get it working. I thing, setting the `PHPRC` environment variable to `D:\path\to\php7` has helped. Wondering, why the `v5` is still working though. But anyway, both version seem to be OK  now.

Comment: Well, if it "seems to be OK now," why not answer your own question?  Exactly *what,* finally, did the trick?

Comment: You're right. It was the `PHPRC` environment variable, that helped. Firstly I thought, it "set" the `php.ini`. But actually it simply manages, which PHP instance has to be called by default (calls of `php` without the full path). After I changed it to from `D:\path\to\php5` to `D:\path\to\php7`, the output of `php --ini` got changed -- the `Loaded Configuration File` is now `D:\path\to\php7\php.ini`. But now there is another problem related to this: There are issues with the IIS and handling of two PHP version at the same time (s. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38503625/2019043)).