# How to set the php.ini path for PHP CGI/FastCGI SAPI on Windows Server 2008 r2?

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008, fastcgi

I have IIS 7.0 and two versions PHP `v5` and `v7` on my Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Standard 6.0 SP2. The problem is, that PHP7 or IIS tries to use the php.ini of PHP5 for IIS "websites".

So on the command line everything is fine:

```
X:\>php -v
PHP 7.0.2 (cli) (built: Jan  6 2016 12:59:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

X:\>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         D:\Data\Programme\php7\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

But in the IIS Manager and in the `phpinfo()` output not:

[image: IIS-website-PHP-setting]

[image: phpinfo-version-sapi-php-ini]

I think, it's a PHP (`cgi-fcgi` SAPI) issue, *not* an IIS issue (but not sure).

**How to set the correct `php.ini` for PHP CGI/FastCGI SAPI on Windows Server 2008?**

---

Also tried it over the Registry, but that didn't help:

[image: registry-php-IniFilePath]

Comment: I know that I had to deal with a similar situation on *Linux,* under *Apache,* but I wonder if the same sort of approach might be used here. Basically, I created two separate "CGI-files," each of which basically comes down to: `exec /path/to/php-cgi --php-ini /path/to/php.ini $PATH_TRANSLATED`. That is to say, the command-file explicitly invokes a PHP interpreter and specifically tells it which `php.ini` file to use. It intuitively seems to me that a similar approach could be cooked-up here . . . (And, P.S.: "I think it's `cgi-fcgi` too.")

Comment: Pondering my previous comment in regard to this being *FastCGI* (regardless of host environment ...), I know that it is possible to designate "separate *pools* of FastCGI worker-bees," and to direct incoming requests to the appropriate one.  You should be able to somehow set up two pools: one for PHP5, the other for PHP7 . . .  Wish I could be more specific, but I haven't done a Windows-hosted project lately.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Thank you for trying to help in this question too! But once again: The problem is not, that the wrong PHP version (or in this case the wrong `php-cgi.exe`) is used. The problem is, that somewhere is configured, that `D:\path\to\php7\php-cgi.exe` has to get its configs from `D:\path\to\php5\php.ini` (instead of `D:\path\to\php7\php.ini`). So I have to find out why it's configured such a strange way and how to change this.

Comment: I acknowledge that my thoughts might not be relevant here, but observe that in my scripts I *do* specify both the exact identity of the PHP executable and `--php-ini`. Apache only "launches a designated CGI process," and it specifies both things. The driver-scripts for FastCGI could be similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38526818/2019043) of [Jan Reilink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1297898/jan-reilink) seems also correct, but unfortunately I could not find out, how to apply it the right way (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503625/how-to-set-the-php-ini-path-for-php-cgi-fastcgi-sapi-on-windows-server-2008-r2?noredirect=1#comment64517694_38526818) and other my comments below Jan's answer).</sup>

Finally I got it solved over the IIS GUI:

[image: IIS GUI -> FastCGI Settings]

And then `FastCGI Settings -> EnvironmentVariables -> PHPRC`:

[image: IIS-FastCGI-Settings-EnvironmentVariables-PHPRC]

See also "[Configure IIS to Handle PHP Requests](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis#Configure_handler_mapping)" in the chapter "Using FastCGI to Host PHP Applications on IIS 7" of the IIS documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set environment variables in your FastCgi configuration to host multiple PHP versions in IIS. The one you want is PHPRC:

```
AppCmd set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi
  /+"[fullPath='c:\php5\php-cgi.exe', arguments='-c
  c:\php5\php.ini'].environmentVariables.
  [name='PHPRC',value='c:\php5\php.ini']" /commit:apphost
```

(note the `-c` argument as well)

and do the same for PHP 7, and change the path. I have this, and more, explained in my blog post https://www.saotn.org/php-wincache-on-iis/.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, the problem seems to be here. I have another Windows Server, where two PHP versions are working well and the difference between these machines is: `C:\...\appcmd list config`: `<application fullPath="D:\Data\Programme\php7\php-cgi.exe" ...><environmentVariables><environmentVariable name="PHPRC" value="D:\Data\Programme\php7\" />...` vs. `<application fullPath="D:\Data\Programme\php7\php-cgi.exe" ...><environmentVariables><environmentVariable name="PHPRC" value="D:\Data\Programme\php\" />...`.

Comment: But when I try `C:\...\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/fastCgi /[fullPath='D:\Data\Programme\php7\php-cgi.exe'].environmentVariables.[name='PHPRC', value='D:\Data\Programme\php7\'] /commit:apphost` I get an error: `ERROR ( message:Cannot find SITE object with identifier "value='D:\Data\Programme\php7\']". )`. Why?

Comment: When I remove the whitespace between `name='PHPRC',` and `value='D:\Data\Programme\php7\'` (`C:\...\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/fastCgi /[fullPath='D:\Data\Programme\php7\php-cgi.exe'].environmentVariables.[name='PHPRC',value='D:\Data\Programme\php7\'] /commit:apphost`), I get another error: `ERROR ( message:Cannot find requested collection element. )`.

Comment: `> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/fastCgi /[fullPath='D:\Data\Programme\php7\php-cgi.exe'].environmentVariables.[name='PHPRC'].value='D:\Data\Programme\php7\' /commit:apphost` returns
`ERROR ( message:Unknown attribute "[fullPath='D:\Data\Programme\php7\php-cgi.exe'].environmentVariables.[name='PHPRC'].value='D:\Data\Programme\php7\'".  Replace with -? for help. )`

Comment: `> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/fastCgi /[fullPath='D:\Data\Programme\php7\php-cgi.exe',arguments='-c D:\Data\Programme\php7\php.ini'].environmentVariables.[name='PHPRC'].value='D:\Data\Programme\php7\' /commit:apphost` returns `ERROR ( message:Cannot find SITE object with identifier "value='D:\Data\Programme\php7\']". )`